# pixel unidad absoluta o relativa ? Para mi es relativa

Tags: css, html5, diseño

> Conversación con alguien que Programa . El decía que el pixel es
> relativo como me parece erróneo encontré lo siguiente

Según el convenio de W3  debemos tomarla como absoluta es una convenios que establece su valor
`1px = 0.75 pt Points 1/72 pulgadas  1 pulg   2,4 cm`  ,
Dicen que hay una traducción de 1998 que la toma de otra forma hoy se toma como absoluta  fuente W3 pero si  que una imagen ocupe un 50%

```
img {
  width: 50%;
}
```

> así cambia de acuerdo al tamaño de la pantalla pero si se toma `px` no
> seria responsive  hay que usar lo anterior para efecto responsive

para 100% en cualquier pantalla  una forma

```
max-width: 100%;
```

tomara el ancho de cualquier pantalla como máximo
Pero insiste en que es relativo en que se adapta a la pantalla ??? y algunos apuntes vi que  dicen que se adapta a la resolución de la Pantalla

[W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#length-units)

Comment: El pixel - o px para abreviar - es el elemento más básico y pequeño de una imagen reproducida digitalmente. De acuerdo con esta descripción, el píxel como tal, es absoluto. Otra cosa es que conviertas el píxel en un punto y modifiques su tamaño (que será de x pixeles).

Comment: `px`, `mm`, `pt`, etc son unidades absolutas. `em`, `%`, `rem`, etc son unidades relativas que heredan del tamaño del contenedor. Leer más en MDN: [Valores y unidades CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units) Incluso hay ejemplos para que los pruebes.

Comment: Yo creo que las medidas *reales* tienen que ver con la impresión. Porque si mido el rectángulo de 72 pt sobre la pantalla de un celular mide menos de 2,5cm https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html

Comment: Es relativo, por que quien realmente define el tamaño del pixel, es la realidad, no la virtualidad. Si tienes una pantalla chiquita con muchisima resolución, el pixel será diminuto. Caso contrario, si es una de estas pantallas gigantes, donde el pixel es más grande que la mano, pasaría lo contrario. Lo importante en esto son los PPP o PPI (Puntos Por Pulgada) - [imagen ejemplo](https://global.samsungdisplay.com/upload/editor/20230913/ajcrcsQyuT_20230913185916.jpg) - fuente: https://global.samsungdisplay.com/31213

Comment: @Excorpion el tamaño de pixel no es relativo... es absoluto... si un pixel tiene un metrica de 10 (in) para una pantalla gigante sigue siendo un tamaño absoluto, que un pixel tenga un tamaño distinto en diferentes dispositivo no lo hace relativo ... **lo que hace relativo al tamaño en pixeles es cuando se manipula en relacion (relativo) a otro objeto.**

si una imagen en esa pantalla de dimensiona a 50% se calcularan los pixel relativos al elemento padre o la pantalla.

Comment: Y porque no han cerrado esta pregunta si claramente está basada en opiniones??

Comment: @OCHOA no esta basada en opiniones ... simplemente hay 2 contextos de implementacion, que pueden ser confusos. pero no hay opiniones... no podes decir que opinas que un pixel es una banana ... un pixel es lo que es ....

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover incluso en la pregunta dice: Para mi es relativa, acá creo que no se discute que es un pixel, sino el hecho de si es una medida absoluta o relativa. Es más en los comentarios ya están unos que es relativa y otros que es absoluta. En resumen, OPINIONES!!!

Comment: @OCHOA que en los comentarios exista una pelea de Opiniones por que ignoran los conceptos, no quiere decir que sea el camino correcto para dar una respuesta... cuando el OP cita Literalmente W3 apoya su tesis sobre un estandar... eso no es discutible.

Comment: Entonces, una pregunta puede tener multiples respuestas y que tenga varias respuesta no quiere decir que sean opiniones ... las 2 o 3 respuestas pueden incluso ser  correctas dependiendo del contexto... y del estandar en el que se apoye. definir si un pixel es absoluto y relativo es muy importante... principalmente en nustro ambiente de programacion y diseño. por un pixel puedes perder el trabajo o ganarte un aumento.

Comment: @OCHOA si no te gusta lo podemos debatir en META... no considero que los comentarios aqui den algun beneficio. saludos.

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover quien rayos va a definir ese concepto acá? ni que fuéramos ARPAnet. No voy, ni necesito debatir nada porque todo esto son opiniones. Lo que no me gusta es que unas preguntas son cerradas rápido y otras las dejan acá.

Comment: pero es que tu opinion de que debe ser cerrada... esta basada en opiniones personales... yo discrepo totalmente del cierre por motivos de "basada en opiniones" no hay manera de que se pueda opinar sobre si un pixel es absoluto o relativo... estas enfocado a satanizar algo que no es opinable...

Comment: Esta pregunta esta mal desde el punto de vista que compara peras con bananas... 40% no es lo mismo que un pixel.. la comparacion no tiene sentido.. uno esta hablando de porcentaje del la muestra (que ni siquiera tiene porque medirse en pixels)... el otro es un pixel, que vale un pixel.. de ahi que la pregunta me sonara rara...

Comment: gbianchi el% es para significar que el px no sirve en formato adaptativo sabes lo que significa ? me parece que no?

Comment: Según lo dicho por Francisco - "...un pixel como unidad absoluta sigue teniendo un contexto relativo incluso dependiendo de la distancia ocular al objetivo." - me basta para confirmar que un pixél es relativo, y por lo tanto como dice Ochoa, la pregunta se basa en opiniones.

Comment: @Excorpion La pregunta no se basa en opiniones porque simplemente es una forma de clasificar el comportamiento de las unidades. Esta clasificación se encuentra en la especificación https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-4/#relative-lengths y en la documentación https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units

Comment: Desde el momento en que unos piensan que... y otros piensan que... esta BASADA EN OPINIONES gentes!!! Aunque sean medidas estandarizadas sigue imperando lo que yo piense/me guste/o use para responder a esta pregunta. Por lo tanto si ESTÁ BASADA EN OPINIONES.

Comment: @OCHOA No es así, una pregunta se cierra por *basada en opiniones* cuando no puede ser respondida con **hechos y/o citas** aquí ciertamente es posible, está la documentación y la especificación.

Answer (score 1):

Que curiosa la pregunta, esto puede generar confusiones, abordemos esto desde diferentes ámbitos.

> Nota: esta pregunta tiene dos respuestas correctas, ya que el pixel o
> las medidas relacionadas a este pueden ser realtivas o absolutas
> dependiendo del contexto. esto no es una opinion, esta basado en los
> estandares y mecanicas de diseño y programacion.

En términos generales, el píxel se considera una unidad absoluta **en el contexto de diseño web**, especialmente cuando se usa en propiedades como el ancho o la altura de un elemento. Por ejemplo, cuando estableces el ancho de una imagen en un 50%, estás diciendo que quieres que ocupe la mitad del ancho de su contenedor padre. entonces el tamaño es relativo a un elemento especifico... pero esa imagen seguira teniendo dimensiones absolutas.

Por otro lado, la interpretación del píxel puede variar dependiendo del contexto y las convenciones de diseño. El estándar de la W3 que citas es la mas utilizada en lo que aqui atañe (programacion) y establece que el píxel debe ser tratado como una unidad absoluta en en todos los casos, pero que esta puede ser establecida. Esto significa que un píxel puede representar una medida física específica, como un punto `(pt)` o una pulgada `(in)`, dependiendo de la resolución del dispositivo de visualización. Importante a la hora de imprimir banners en general.

Por ejemplo: en una pantalla con una densidad de píxeles `(PPI)` de 96, un píxel podría ser aproximadamente igual a 0.75 puntos `(pt)`, pero en una pantalla de mayor resolución, como las pantallas Retina, un píxel podría corresponder a un punto. Entonces **electronicamente**, podemos estar hablando de medidas relativas.

Entonces... aunque técnicamente el píxel puede tener una interpretación absoluta, en la práctica se usa principalmente de manera relativa para lograr diseños adaptables y responsivos. Utilizando porcentajes o valores relativos como `50%`, `100%`, o `max-width: 100%`, podemos crear diseños que se ajusten a diferentes tamaños de pantalla de manera efectiva.

***Ahora en programacion web***, para el uso he implementacion en CSS tenemos los siguientes ejemplo:

```css
.size-img {
    width: 200px; /* Establece el ancho a 200 píxeles absoluto*/
    height: 100px; /* Establece la altura a 100 píxeles absoluto*/
    border: 1px solid black; /* Añade un borde para visualización absoluto*/
}
```

o podemos tener:

```css
.size-img {
    width: 50%; /* Establece el ancho al 50% relativo del contenedor padre */
    padding-top: 25%; /* Establece el relleno superior al 25% del contenedor padre, creando un cuadrado relativo */
    background-color: lightblue; /* Añade un color de fondo para visualización relativo  */
}
```

Estoy seguro que dependiendo de la implementacion y el contexto un pixel puede ser una metrica relativa o absoluta, o mejor dicho los elementos que lo implementan pueden trabajar bajo esos dos contextos.

consideraria lo siguiente, una imagen puede tener 100px * 100px, eso nunca cambia es un tamaño absoluto, peroooo se usan tamaños relativos en diseño, por ejemplo si el div padre de la imagen mide 100px, y a la imagen se le pone un setting de 50%, el tamaño de la imagen sera renderizado al 50% del tamaño del div (elemento padre)... esto provoca que la vista sea realitiva (en este contexto), aunque la imagen siga siendo de 100px originalmente.

Cito a W3:

> Las unidades de longitud absoluta están fijas entre sí. Son
> principalmente útiles cuando se conoce el entorno de salida. Las
> unidades absolutas constan de unidades físicas (pulg, cm, mm, pt, pc) y el px
> ... 
> La siguiente imagen ilustra el efecto de la distancia de visualización
> en el tamaño de un píxel de referencia: una distancia de lectura de 71
> cm (28 pulgadas) da como resultado un píxel de referencia de 0,26 mm,
> mientras que una distancia de lectura de 3,5 m (12 pies) da como
> resultado un píxel de referencia de 1,3 mm.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el mejor ejemplo, en donde un pixel como unidad absoluta sigue teniendo un contexto relativo incluso dependiendo de la distancia ocular al objetivo.

Comment: eh... te estas contradiciendo... width: 50% no dice que es el 50% de un pixel.. y el padre puede estar representado en cualquier medida... o sea, no entiendo donde dejas claro que es relativo.. un pixel es un pixel.. 50% es relativo.. 1 px es un px...,

Comment: @gbianchi estoy citando y ejemplificando mi respuesta para que tega sentido cabo de hacer una actualizacion...

Comment: segun eso que pusiste...  Las unidades absolutas constan de unidades físicas .... y el px.. fin de la discusion.. jajajaj

Comment: sigue siendo un pixel.. no es medio pixel.. ni nada.. un pixel es un pixel.. no es relativo.. no depende de otras cosas en la visualizacion... es un pixel...

Comment: de ahi, a que pueda ser mas grande o mas chico dependiendo el viewport, no lo hace relativo... sigue siendo absoluto...

Comment: no he dicho que sea medio pixel jajajajaja ... mmm si me ayudas a ver donde doy a entender semejante barrabazada para arreglar mas mi respuesta ... lo agradeceria

Comment: al decir que es relativo.. estas diciendo que depende de otras cosas.. y no, la verdad que no depende de otras cosas.. cuando vos decis que tu lo que sea, mide 5 pixel, mide 5 pixels.. siempre... no mide 10, no mide 3.. mide 5... de ahi, a que dependiendo el lugar donde lo pongas, se vea mas grande o mas chico, no lo hace relativo.. sigue midiendo 5 pixels...

Comment: lo que acabas de decir es lo que pretendia plasmas: una imagen puede tener 100px*100px, eso nunca cambia, peroooo se usan tamaños relativos, por ejemplo si el div padre de la imagen mide 100px, y a la imagen se le pone un setting de 50%, el tamaño de la imagen sera renderizado al 50% del tamaño del div... esto provoca que la vista sea realitiva, aunque la imagen siga siendo de 100px originalmente.

Comment: no no.. mide 100px X 100 px... no hay nada de relativo en eso... cuando vos hablas de 1 medida, esa medida se mantiene... si vos relativizas en un viewport por OTROS MEDIOS (decir que se vea al 50%) no hace que el pixel sea relativo, lo que es relativo es tu visualizacion, pero 1 pixel sigue siendo un pixel, y tu imagen sigue midiendo 100px X 100px.. lo que cambio es tu relacion de aspecto, pero el pixel, sigue siendo un pixel...

Comment: no he dicho que "no hace que el pixel sea relativo" dije que la vista/renderizado se hace relativa al elemento de referencia ...

Comment: "el píxel se considera una unidad relativa en el contexto de diseño web," no es relativo.. un pixel es un pixel...

Comment: @gbianchi haaa meti la dos patas XD... ya lo he corregido ...

Answer (score 0):

> La respuesta es W3 tomo como a una de las medidas absolutas al px

> Es así es absoluta pero en cada dispositivo por ejemplo distintos celulares su tamaño puede depender de la gama del dispositivo de su resolución podemos tener celulares de igual tamaño pero de distinta resolución

> Asi en ese dispositivo particular el px tendrá una medida absoluta para el cada dispositivo particular

> Lo que se menciono sobre  la apreciación del observador jamás puede
> cambiar una medida absoluta

.

> Sinceramente pensé siempre que era  absoluta pero dados otros
> argumentos que tampoco me parecían validos en la conversación que
> surge de la pregunta definitivamente no puede decirse que en
> determinadas circunstancias el px se comporte como relativo en un mismo dispositivo.

> siempre será absoluto el px para un mismo dispositivo

Answer (score 0):

Las *unidades relativas y absolutas* son una forma de clasificar las unidades en el diseño web.

Las unidades relativas lo son cuando **su dimensión depende de la dimensión de otro elemento presente en el documento**. Es decir, es relativo a otro elemento. Por ejemplo, tenemos un `div` cualquiera y seteamos:

- height: 50% -> El elemento es tiene un alto del 50% del primer ancestro que tenga definida la altura, siendo este ancestro el elemento a quien es relativo
- width: 20vh -> El elemento tiene un ancho del 20% al viewport ("la pantalla útil"), siendo el viewport el elemento a quien es relativo
- font: 1em -> El tamaño de la fuente es del 100% del tamaño de la fuente de su ancestro (es relativo a su ancestro)

Por otro lado, las unidades absolutas no varían dentro del documento y no dependen de ningún ancestro y otro elemento. Un `div` con `with:23cm` medirá siempre lo mismo, en cualquier parte del documento.

**El pixel (px) es una unidad absoluta**, su dimensión no se ve afectada por ningún otro elemento del documento y así es como se encuentra clasificada en la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units)

---

Dicho en otras palabras, las unidades relativas son **dependientes** de otro elemento, Es decir la dimensión del elemento `A` depende de la dimensión del elemento `B`, si cambio `B` cambiará `A`. Lo cual no pasará con unidades abosulutas